# How to concatenate string array into a single string

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am trying to concatenate a whole array of string into a single array for printing purpose.

```
function getArray() public view returns (string) 
{
    arr.push("Max");
    arr.push("good");
    arr.push("well");
    .
    . 
    .
    //arr[]-Array of strings
    //b-string type variable
    return b;
}
```

output should be like -Maxgoodwell

Comment: For clarity of your question, you should have the `arr.push` part in a different function.

Comment: Why? What is your use case that would make this an appropriate thing to do on chain?

Comment: Usually, everything related to displaying information on the screen should be done client-side, not in the smart contract.

Comment: @JesseBusman: True. Unless this functionality should somehow be used on-chain (i.e., by another contract), there's no point implementing it. This question is lacking the context required for determining whether or not this function is to be called from another conttract, but I doubt that this is indeed the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!

```
string company_name;
function getComp(string memory arr) public returns (string memory) 
{
    company_name=concate(arr);
}

function concate(string memory arr) internal view returns(string memory)
{
    return string(abi.encodePacked(company_name," ",arr));
}

function ShowComp() public view returns (string memory)
{
    return company_name;
}
```

Comment: You are not really concatenating an adhoc array of strings, but three well known variables.